# fill column in panda dataframe with result of groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to pandas, and can't solve this problem myself. I have a dataframe prices and here is prices.tail(5):
[image]

now I run this code:

```
prices['dollar_vol'] = (prices
                    .groupby('ticker',
                             group_keys=False,
                             as_index=False)
                    .dollar_vol
                    .rolling(window=21)
                    .mean()
                    .fillna(0)
                    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

and now dollar_vol filled with NaN. here is prices.tail(5)
[image]

I am working in google's Colab. It was working correctly month ago and suddenly stopped working. Please help.

Comment: print your `prices.groupby()...` thingies out and you would see that the data has different index than `prices`

Comment: I did that  and for prices.groupby() index is only ticker. Not ticker and date. So how would you suggest I should fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `prices` is sorted by `ticker` then `date` with

```
prices.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

And then you can pass the underlying numpy array:

```
prices['dollar_vol'] = (prices
                    .groupby('ticker')         # no need for other stuff
                    .dollar_vol
                    .rolling(window=21)
                    .mean()
                    .fillna(0)
                    .to_numpy() )              # the numpy array
```

Another way is to use `transform` without the need of sorting:

```
prices['dollar_vol'] = (prices
                        .groupby('ticker')         # no need for other stuff
                        .dollar_vol
                        .transform( lambda x: x.rolling(window=21)
                                               .mean().fillna(0)
                                   )
                        )
```

Comment: Thank you it solved the problem. Could you explain why? Or point me to material so I could understand problem better. Thank you.

Comment: If you pass a series to series/column assignment, Pandas will align the index. So series data can be re-ordered/drop/add when the two indexes are not aligned. If you pass a list/np.array, the raw data is passed in that order. That's why you need to make sure you have the data in the correct order.

Comment: @user1272913 also see the updated answer for another option. Note that `transform` on lambda function is a little slower than the previous approach.